# TFS IEventService "Event type CheckinEvent does not exist"

Tags: tfs

I am trying to subscribe to `CheckinEvent` in TFS 2010 using TFS `IEventService`. For some reason I keep getting:

> Event type <<event type>> does not exist

for `WorkItemChangedEvent` and `CheckinEvent`. What am I doing wrong?

```cs
var serverUri = new Uri("http://TFS_SERVICE:8080/tfs");
var server = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(serverUri);

var eventService = server.GetService<IEventService>();
var preference = new DeliveryPreference
    {
         Schedule = DeliverySchedule.Immediate,
         Type = DeliveryType.Soap,
          Address = "http://localhost:61773/NotifyService.asmx"
     };

int eventId = eventService.SubscribeEvent("CheckinEvent", null, preference);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are querying the Event Service at the Configuration Server level. These event types only exist at the team project collection level, which I assume is where you actually want to create your event subscription. You would need to change your code to something like the following:

```cs
var serverUri = new Uri("http://TFS_SERVICE:8080/tfs/collection");

TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUri);
var eventService = collection.GetService<IEventService>();

var preference = new DeliveryPreference
{
  Schedule = DeliverySchedule.Immediate,
  Type = DeliveryType.Soap,
  Address = "http://localhost:61773/NotifyService.asmx"
};

int eventId = eventService.SubscribeEvent("CheckinEvent", null, preference);
```

Please note that the URI needs to include your collection name.

Comment: I used your code.. and for some reason when I checkin some code in the collection I specific in the url I don't get the "Notify" web method called..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `TfsConfigurationServerFactory`, use the `TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection()` method. These events exist at the collection level, rather than the server level.